# Why is this equation not producing the correct return?

Tags: java

Here is the segment of code that I'm having trouble with.  No matter if the circles intersect the program is returning that they do not intersect.  What am I missing here?

```
if(intersectCir(xBlue, yBlue, radBlue, xRed, yRed, radRed) == true) {
         System.out.println("The blue circle intersects the red circle.");
     } else if(intersectCir(xBlue, yBlue, radBlue, xRed, yRed, radRed) != true){
         System.out.println("The blue circle does not intersect the red circle.");
     }

     if(intersectCir(xBlue, yBlue, radBlue, xGreen, yGreen, radGreen) == true) {
         System.out.println("The blue circle intersects the green circle.");
     } else if(intersectCir(xBlue, yBlue, radBlue, xGreen, yGreen, radGreen) != true){
         System.out.println("The blue circle does not intersect the green circle.");
     }

     if(intersectCir(xGreen, yGreen, radGreen, xRed, yRed, radRed) == true) {
         System.out.println("The green circle intersects the red circle.");
     } else if(intersectCir(xBlue, yBlue, radBlue, xRed, yRed, radRed) != true){
         System.out.println("The green circle does not intersect the red circle.");
     }
 }




 public static boolean intersectCir(int x1, int y1, int rad1, int x2, int y2, int rad2) {
     if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2)) + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2))) <= (rad1 + rad2));
         return true;
 }
```

}

Comment: pretty much all of that code is pointless. all you had to show was the `intersectCir()` method and explain what the parameters are... we don't care where the data's coming from if the problem has to do with USING the data.

Comment: Have you tried adding "else return false;" to the "if" inside function "intersectCir" ?

Comment: There's a semicolon after the `if` statement, so the next line is always executing.

Comment: I have removed the extra code.  No matter if they intersect it displays that they do not.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your distance formula was mistranslated. Corrected and commented below:

```
  public static boolean intersectCir(int x1, int y1, int rad1, int x2, int y2, int rad2) {
    //distance formula, applied:
    //    ((x1-x2)^2+(y1-y2)^2)^0.5 <= rad1+rad2
    final int xdiff = x1 - x2;
    final int ydiff = y1 - y2;
    final int totalRad = rad1 + rad2;
    //    ((xdiff)^2+(ydiff)^2)^0.5 <= totalRad
    final int distanceSquared = xdiff * xdiff + ydiff * ydiff;//beware overflow!
    //    (distanceSquared)^0.5 <= totalRad
    //square roots are hard, better to just square both sides:
    //    distanceSquared <= totalRad^2
    return distanceSquared <= totalRad * totalRad;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this method seems clearer than the square root formula and worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is your corrected method.

```
public static boolean intersectCir(int x1, int y1, int rad1, int x2, int y2, int rad2) {
 if(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x1 - x2, 2)) + (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(y1 - y2, 2))) <= (rad1 + rad2))
     return true;
 else
     return false;
```

}

Comment: Can you explain what you did for @pocjt9324

Comment: Even with the changes it still displays that they don't intersect when they do.